# Check if element is in selected area of page

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Using JavaScript (without JQuery) how can I tell if a particular element on a web-page is selected?

For example, I have a web-page, and I select a portion of the page. By **"select"** I mean to:

- Left-click the mouse (and hold the mouse button down) at a position on the web-page where the selection will begin.
- Drag the mouse to the end of the desired selection area.
- Release the mouse button to complete the selection.

(**Note:** I really didn't think I needed to provide this level of detail for ***"select a portion of the page"***, but many seem to be confused about what I meant).

Then in JavaScript, I want to look at some elements and identify any of them that are within the selected area of the web page:

```
function a(e){
  /** 
   *  I want to find out if element "e" is within the
   *  "Selected" area of the web-page, and take some action if it is.
   *  (not to be confused with "checked" or "unchecked" for "checkbox"
   *  elements, or "selected" for "option" elements).
  **/ 
}

var x,k,f,j,r;
x=document.forms;
for(k=0;k<x.length;++k){
   f=x[k];
   for(j=0;j<f.length;++j){
      r=(f[j].type.toLowerCase());
      if(r=="checkbox")
         a(f[j]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, minified code.

Comment: Your question is not clear by what you mean by selected? Do you mean clicking on a checkbox and seeing if it is "selected" aka "checked", or do you actually mean dragging your mouse across the page selecting the text/elements? What is your end goal and please use real variable names, their are minifiers for a reason.

Comment: It is not that hard to read. Loop over all forms and look at each element to see if it is a checkbox. OP then wants to see if it is in a selection the user made on the page.

Comment: @epascarello - I mean a *"selected area of the web-page"*. I have added more detail to the question to clarify this. Also, ***"... please use real variable names ..."***: The example code has ***not*** been "minified". I have used ***"real"*** variable names. They are minimally named because: 1) that portion of the code is not directly important to the actual question, and 2) I am putting this code into a bookmark which allows a limited number of characters.

Comment: It was the inclusion of not very relevant code including a checkbox and the word selected that confused people

Comment: @mplungjan - When I asked the question, I understood the possibility for confusion, but I thought: ***"I select a portion of the page..."*** and then ***"... identify any of them that are within the selected area of the web page"*** was sufficient to avoid that confusion. Apparently, I was wrong. The problem with asking code questions on SO is if you don't include any code, you are often not taken seriously, and even downvoted. So, often, the code you ***can*** include is not actually relavent to the actual question being asked, because code that's relavent is not yet known to the asker.

Comment: @mplungjan - I was disappointed that your answer was removed... it was so very close to working.

Comment: Well it go down voted and was more like work than it was worth for me to spend time on. As I mentioned in a comment, SO is not elancing.com and without a complete understanding of what you actually want and without access to your html, I did not feel that I could give a final answer. If you want, we can take it offline. My address is in my profile, but no promises that it will work well cross browser

Answer (score 0):

So check if it is "selected" by looking at the checked property of the element.

```
console.log(e.checked);
```

So as a if statemenet:

```
if (e.checked) {
   //do action checked
} else {
  //do action unchecked
}
```

Comment: Selected - portion of the page is selected!

Comment: @mplungjan So you downvoted everyone on an unclear question. Awesome dude, just awesome.

Comment: Poor example but clear question. And i commented on every downvote, not like some 50% of downvotes I received here...  Just hoping people would pay better attention and I can revert my downvote if answer is fixed

Answer (score -1):

Here a DOM property `.ckecked` exist for check a check-box is selected or not.

If a check-box is checked/selected it's return `true` and if not checked/selected then return `false`.

Comment: See the other answers and my comments to them. He wants to know if some object is inside a document.selection. At least spell the property correctly